# using PARSE Push notification without app id

Tags: ios, push-notification, parse-platform

I am developing an iOS app that's almost finished. I want to add remote push notification service via PARSE Api. My question is do I have to have my app already submitted to AppStore and have an App Id at hand to start this service. Or Can I complete my development before submitting it to App Store?

Comment: Have you read the parse docs? How could you add APNS after the app is submitted?

Comment: as an update to an already existing app, that was the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to have the app submitted and approved by Apple before you can add Push Notifications through the Parse API.

The Parse tutorial for Push Notifications only requires you to have an App ID for your app. As the tutorial explains, you can generate an App ID using the 'Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles' section of the Apple Developer Member Center.

- **Parse Tutorial:** https://parse.com/tutorials/ios-push-notifications
- **Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles:** https://developer.apple.com/account/overview.action
- **App IDs:** https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifiers/bundle/bundleList.action

You will need to become a Registered Apple Developer to access this section of the Apple Developer Member Center.